# SQL query using Temporary table Versus Actual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

What is preferable and advantages for processing using temp table or process using actual table in SQL Server 2016 and above?

These are the SQL queries for processing using temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST #temp1;

SELECT 
    a.col1 AS col1, a.col2 AS col2, 
    b.col1 AS col3, b.col2 AS col4
INTO #temp1
FROM table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.col1 = 'best_practice'
   OR a.col1 = 'performance' ;

INSERT INTO schema1.destination_table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
    FROM #temp1 ;
```

These are the SQL queries using actual table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE schema1.process_table;

INSERT INTO schema1.process_table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT 
        a.col1 AS col1, a.col2 AS col2, 
        b.col1 AS col3, b.col2 AS col4
    FROM 
        table1 AS a
    INNER JOIN 
        table2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE 
        a.col1 = 'performance'
        OR a.col1 = 'performance' ;

INSERT INTO schema1.destination_table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
    FROM #temp1;
```

DDL (Data Definition Language) script for process table:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.destination_table
( 
    col1 AS VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    col2 AS VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    col3 AS VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    col4 AS VARCHAR(10) NULL  
);
```

Comment: Local temp tables are viable option when you need them visible for single session(the one that created them) for one time usage. Second scenario is read-only replica. You may need to "materialize" the result for some data analysis and you are not allowed to create ordinary table

Answer (score 0):

Here are some key findings

1. Temporary tables are persisted in the disk where your ***tempdb*** is located whereas permanent table is persisted where you actual database is located
2. Scope of local temp table is session specific, that means if you have two concurrent processes having same temp table name, both processes will have their own temp table. Whereas in permanent table, you need to take extra care if same table is being used by another process at same time.
3. Temp tables will be automatically removed after the session ends whereas you need to manually drop(if you wish to) actual table.

You should use temporary table to perform intermediate operations before inserting data in actual table.
Refer to [SQL Server Temp Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables) for more information about temp tables.

P.S.: Although temp table is dropped automatically when session ends, it is recommended to drop temp table manually if it is no longer needed in session.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no need or advantage to using a temporary table for this purpose.  Using temporary tables just means that you are going to incur extra overhead for reading and writing the data.  On some database systems, temporary storage space is optimized to use fast hardware, but there is still additional overhead.

In general, I strongly recommend depending on the database optimizer for performance.  Many, many person years of effort has gone into the optimizers.  They usually do quite well, and when they don't, a `HINT` is usually sufficient.

There are some rare cases where temporary tables can speed query processing; three come to mind:

- If an expression is needed more than once within a query or across queries, then temporary tables ensure that it is processed only once.
- The temporary tables have better statistics than the results of complex operations.  This can help the optimizer.
- Indexes can be added to temporary tables to speed subsequent processing.

If you are just saving the results in another table, none of these is relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, appreciated